# php how to get the binary array from an mp3 file

Tags: php, arrays, binary

and I want to store the byte of the audio file in array 
MORE INFO: I'd like to have users upload a small file through a form, and return the binary representation of that file as a binary string - i.e ones and zeros.

Comment: `echo file_get_contents($filename)` ?